# MultiValueDictKeyError when Djano Imagefield is blank

Tags: django-models

I have a very simple model and form which expects user to fill in name , title etc. and also upload an image . Everything works fine but as soon as user tries to submit a record without uploading the image then it gets Multivaluedictkey error. I have set null =true and blank = true in the field definition. :"photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='media',null=True,blank=True)" . Media storage and retrieval is also working fine as long as image is uploaded by the user.In short I request your help in suggesting snything which enables me to let user submit a record without necessarily uploading an image.

```
Traceback:
File "/home/sampledemo/.virtualenvs/django18/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/sampledemo/mysite/polls/views.py" in someview
  45.             newproject.photo = request.FILES['photo']
File "/home/sampledemo/.virtualenvs/django18/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py" in __getitem__
  322.             raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))

Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /someview/
Exception Value: "'photo
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have

```
newproject.photo = request.FILES['photo']
```

you will get `MultiValueDictKeyError` for the following reasons
 1. `request.FILES` does not have the key named `photo`
 2. `request.FILES` may have multiple values for the same key

If it's the 2nd case you should use `request.FILES.getlist('photo')` [if you upload multiple files with the same. In your case it's 'photo']